# How to get the real scroll height of div (say, inner text size)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to make a auto-scrolling div that go to its top when it reaches the end. But it doesn't work...

```
function    scrollPannel()
{
    var pannel = document.getElementById('pannel');
    if (typeof scrollPannel.count == 'undefined')
    {
        scrollPannel.count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollPannel.count += 2;
    }
// trouble is here
    if ((scrollPannel.count - pannel.scrollHeight) > pannel.clientHeight)
    {
        scrollPannel.count = 0;
    }
    pannel.scrollTop = scrollPannel.count;
    setTimeout('scrollPannel()', 500);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='pannel'  style="height:200px;overflow:auto" onmouseover="sleepScroll()">
    <p>...</p><!-- long text -->
</div>
```

And after, I will need to find how to stop scrolling when "onmouseover" occures.

EDIT: I did not explained the problem clearly. In fact, I have tried something like:

```
if (scrollPannel.count > pannel.scrollHeight)
{
    scrollPannel.count = 0;
}
```

The problem is that scrollHeight seems greater than div inner text. So it makes a lot of time to return to the top.

So I need an element property of which I could use the value to compare with my count variable. However I don't know Javascript a lot and I could not find anything. I hope it is as well simple as I think of it.

Comment: What is the function sleepscroll()?

Comment: sleepScroll() is a function to implement that I would use to stop scrolling on event "onmouseover". In my case, I think it will be a simple clearTimeout() call.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
// calculate max scroll top position (go back to top once reached)
var maxScrollPosition = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
// example
element.scrollTop = maxScrollPosition;
```

That should do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the scrollHeight property.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight

Comment: You know what, I've thought of it o/
Acutally what I've tried first was:

If (count < pannel.scrollHeight)...

But doesn't work, scrollHeight seems too great

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have involves jQuery, hope that's not a problem.

JavaScript:

```
var timeout;
function scrollPannel()
{
    var divHeight = $("#pannel").height() / 2;
    var scrollCount = $("#pannel").scrollTop();
    var scrollHeight = $("#inside").height() - 20 - divHeight;
    scrollCount += 2;

    if ((scrollCount - scrollHeight) > 0)
    {
        scrollCount = 0;
    }
    $("#pannel").scrollTop(scrollCount);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(scrollPannel(), 100);
}

function scrollStop() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='pannel' onmouseover="scrollStop();" onmouseout="scrollPannel();">
    <p id="inside"></p><!-- long text -->
</div>
```

Explanation:
jQuery's `.height()` of the inside element `<p>` gives us the actual height you're looking for, but it's not enough for reaching the bottom, since that happens before we reach the element's height. A little investigation shows that the "top" of `scrollTop()` is about half way inside the original `div`'s height. You may need to play around with `divHeight` to get the exact results you're looking for.

Of course, I also included a method for stopping and continuing scrolling.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't know a lot about JS, and not at all concerning JQuery. I would prefer to find a solution that don't anything else than JS (say, preferably without libs).
Of course, if I can't find any other solution, I will think about yours. Anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the element's actual height without using jQuery. I suggest you take a bit to learning it, it's a very powerful tool :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollHeight` property but to call it, you need to use an index like that:

```
$('#pannel')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the scrollTop and scrollLeft to really high silly values they only ever get set as their maximum allowed values which I think is what you need? You can then use them to work out the scroll center if you wished.

See snippet example.

```js
var mB = document.getElementById('myBox');
var mR = document.getElementById('myResult');

// Set the top and the left to silly values
mB.scrollTop = 99999999;
mB.scrollLeft = 99999999;

// They will only end up being set as their max
mR.innerHTML = "maxTop="+mB.scrollTop+"<br>maxLeft="+mB.scrollLeft;

// Now take the max values and divide by 2 to scroll back to middle.
mB.scrollTop = mB.scrollTop/2;
mB.scrollLeft = mB.scrollLeft/2;
```

```css
#myBox{
overflow:auto;
}
#myContent{
border:1px solid black;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='myBox' style='width:300px;height:300px'>
     <div id='myContent' style='width:500px;height:800px;line-height:800px;'><center>I am the center of the content</center></div>
</div>
<div id='myResult'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got one solution....

```
function findMaxReach(){
let maxReach =0

document.querySelector('.YourElement').scrollLeft = 100000;
maxReach = document.querySelector('.YourElement').scrollLeft;
document.querySelector('.YourElement').scrollLeft = 0;

return maxReach
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).